# Angular JS Service Promise for Massaged Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am new to Angular and javascript and need a bit of help.

I have a service that will need to aggregate data from various locations. I am building a sub-service to pull data from one of these locations. This subservice needs to 1) retrieve data from a REST web service, 2) massage it a bit and 3) return the final data to the invoking service.

I have steps 1 and 2 working, however I am running into a problem on the third. In general, I am having a hard time understanding promises. Yes, I've read the documentation, googled around, even saw a cartoon on it, still can't figure it out.... Anyway, here is the relevant code:

```
app.service('advsolr',['$http',function($http) {
    var DEBUG = false;
    var conf = get_conf();
    var solr = 'serverurl';
    var res = {};
    var data = {};

    this.query =  function(searchp) {
        //Run Search
        query_solr(searchp);
        return data;
    };


    var query_solr = function(search) {
        var g = 'serverurl' //works fine
        if (DEBUG) { console.log(g);}

        $http.get(g).then(function(response){
            res = response.data; // this works
            parse_search_res(); //this massages the data and sticks it in the data object
            return data; //this does absolutely nothing here
        });
    };
}]);
```

The main query method is ran by the other service. This queries a Solr instance, gets the results and massages them into the format I want. I know I can do this elsewhere, but I want to have this as a standalone service for portability and plus I just want this to work dammit.

So the query method runs, I had some other stuff in there, but I took it out for this example since it would not add value. It hits query_solr which gets the data and massages it with parse_search_res, which sticks it into the data global variable.

Now the issue is that query method returns the empty data before parse_search_res had a chance to load the data in it. How can I prevent the query method from returning without the data?

Thanks

Comment: It isn't possible for `this.query` to return the data directly, it must return a promise.

Comment: as you've already stated, you need to use promises. You can create a promise, and then run a function after your first function finishes. This is called promise chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of promises is that you initiate some asynchronous operation like AJAX request, then you return corresponding promise object, and a consumer code uses this promise's methods to provide callback function on promise state change.

So to fix your code you need to make `query_solr` return promise:

```
app.service('advsolr', ['$http',function($http) {
    var DEBUG = false;
    var conf = get_conf();
    var solr = 'serverurl';
    var res = {};
    var data = {};

    var query_solr = function(search) {
        var g = 'serverurl' //works fine
        if (DEBUG) { console.log(g);}

        return $http.get(g).then(function(response){
            res = response.data; // this works
            return parse_search_res();
        });
    };

    this.query =  function(searchp) {
        return query_solr(searchp);
    };
}]);
```

You'll also need to change parse_search_res() to return the massaged data instead of saving it into the "data" variable.

And having set up `advsolr` service like that, one could use it like this:

```
advsolr.query('something').then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: You are the man! Will accept it as answer when 15mins are up. Just to make sure I understand... $http promise is returned to originating service through this.query right? The .then in advsolr will run when the data is ready, but where does that return go? Is the .then in the outer module running on the same promise?

Comment: I guess I am trying to lay this out sequentially and I am having problems wrapping my head around what happens when and to what?

Comment: `$http` methods like `get` returns promises. Promise have methods like `then` which you use to provide a callback function, to be invoked when asyn operation is ready. In case of AJAX request promise will be resolved once response has come from the server. But cool thing is that inside of promise `then` callbacks you can modify promise object which will be passed to the next `then` block. If you are interested in understanding how promises works you might find useful [this](http://dfsq.info/site/read/promise-pattern-explained) writeup on reimplementing promise pattern.